# Why Does ToList throw an Exception when only 1 record is returned

Tags: c#, linq

I have a lambda expression that finds all of the labels on a form that contain the name of a particular method (labels are created dynamically and contain a prefix and the method name).  The expression removes the prefix and evaluates whether what is left matches the method name.  All was working fine until I ran across a method that returned only one label.   When it hits this line:

```
var labels = methodLabels
    .Where(t => t.Name.Remove(0, t.Name.IndexOf(d.Name)) == d.Name)
    .ToList();
```

It throws an exception "Count cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: count".  However, if I change ToList() to FirstOrDefault(), it works just fine and returns the correct label.  This is in a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var d in remainingMethods)
{
    var labels = methodLabels.Where(t => t.Name.Remove(0, t.Name.IndexOf(d.Name)) == d.Name).ToList();

    foreach (var l in labels)
```

I'm not finding anything online that addresses my issue.  If anyone knows why this is occurring or can help with a work around, I would appreciate it.  I cannot just change it to FirstOrDefault() in case the query does return more than one record.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you use `FirstOrDefault`, the enumeration is evaluated only until the first match is found. If the `ToList` throws that exception, then `methodLabels` has at least 2 elements, and one of them returns negative for `t.Name.IndexOf(d.Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception `"Count cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: count".` is referring to the second parameter in the [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. `IndexOf` is likely returning negative 1 when the method name is not found in your string. Since using remove within the lambda does not actually allow you to return a list with the prefix removed, you could consider simply using `String.Contains`. If that however is too broad and can possibly return false positives, you can update your current check to cater for when the method name is not found.

```cs
var labels = methodLabels
    .Where(t => t.Name.Remove(0, Math.Max(0,t.Name.IndexOf(d.Name))) == d.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Cannot use contains.  That is what we had first and it was returning extras.  I'll try your suggestion and see if it works.  Sounds reasonable.  Thanks much for your help.

Comment: AWESOME!  Worked like a charm!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is coming from the `Remove` method call, because the `IndexOf` method returns a `-1` for one of the items in `methodLabels` as its `Name` does **not** contain the value in `d.Name`.

When you do `FirstOrDefault`, as mentioned by [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto), it will return the first one that matches your `Where` predicate and will stop processing the next items in `methodLabels`; but when you do `ToList` it will go over **all** of the items in `methodLabels` and one of the items will cause the error to be thrown.

See the documentation for [`String.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> **Exceptions**
>   [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) Either `startIndex` or `count` is less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
var labels = methodLabels
    .Where(t => t.Name.Remove(0, Math.Max(0, t.Name.IndexOf(d.Name))) == d.Name)
    .ToList();
```